# How to control the Beacon Development Kit ibeacon scan time?

Tags: shell, raspberry-pi, ibeacon

I bought the Beacon Development Kit from radiusnetwork. When I try to write scripts in shell in the Raspberry Pi beacon, when I add the "ibeacon scan", it will scan the nearby beacons constantly.  I would like to scan ibeacon like 5 or 10 seconds, and stop the command "ibeacon scan" What should I do?

Hope to receive your suggestions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

BLE is designed to be low power drain
see aisle labs report - http://www.aislelabs.com/?p=254

peripheral mode in the detecting smart device allows powering down
see Radius networks http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/12/15/why-android-devices-cant-act-as-ibeacons.html

Comment: and..
for a 'beacon' to be an 'beacon' has certain specs 100ms continuous advertising
see Apple MFI specs http://bit.ly/1pyLWZ7

Comment: Neither this post nor its author's subsequent comment addresses any part of the question which was asked.

Answer (score 3):

The scan function on the Beacon Development Kit runs indefinitely until interrupted by CTRL+C or the process is killed.  There is not a feature built into the function that allows a scan to terminate after some time.  One way you can accomplish this is to capture the PID of the scan process after it is called in your shell script. Then you can kill the process whenever you want the scan to stop (e.g., after 5 or 10 seconds).  Here's an example:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 sudo /etc/ibeacon/ibeacon_scan &
 scan_pid=$!
 sleep 5
 sudo kill -2 $scan_pid
```

Note: you have to call the scan script directly to get the proper PID.  In addition, using the `-2` option with the `kill` command will send the SIGINT signal, allowing the scan script to exit properly.

Comment: Why it shows sudo /etc/ibeacon/ibeacon_scan command not find?

Comment: Because you either don't have that script installed in that location, the appropriate execute bit for your user is not set on it, or else because you don't have /bin/bash on which it depends available to execute it (or you are on a system that doesn't have a 'sudo').

Comment: @Billy which version of the development kit do you have?  It should say on the instructions page.

Comment: @Billy We temporarily removed the download and will be launching a new version soon.  For now, replace that line with this and it should work: `sudo /etc/ibeacon/ibeacon_scan.rb &`